# Fanatic badge issue

Tags: discussion, badges

I have been active for 100 days in a row in the past and was rewarded the fanatic badge (https://space.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/fanatic). It has happened again that I visited this site for 100 days in a row, but I wasn’t rewarded the same badge. Is it only possible to get the badge once or is it an error with the algorithm?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get one Fanatic badge.

Badges, rep and privileges are network wide, so your best bet is to look on meta.stackexchange.com for [questions like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99168/154443) or for questions tagged [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)

Comment: I don’t understand why it is possible to get some badges more than once, but not others.

Comment: Because that is the way they have been designed. They are to reward behaviours considered positive on Stack Exchange. I would imagine once you have Fanatic, you have shown you can keep coming back for 100 days. The aim should not be to get badges - they are a side effect of doing the right things.

Comment: Because some badges are more important than others to repeat. Great answer is a lot better than fanatic. Multiple fanatics show nothing, multiple great answers show a lot. @TheRocketfan